# Atom Editor Customize Default Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, html, atom-editor

I am a web developer and using Atom as text editor but I always have to change some autocomplete suggestions.

For example when I type `html` and pres tab it gives me this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

This result is not actually what so I manually change it like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
  <meta name="author" content="Your name">
  <meta name="description" content="Brief description">
  
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#00FFF0">
  
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I did a research and everybody solves this kind of similar issues with `snippets` **I am not asking how can I do it with snippet. I already know it.** I want to change these codes from editor's current location. Possibly it locates somewhere in `~/AppData/Local/atom` but I haven't found it yet. I want to reach that file and change related suggestions from there.

This is not only for `html` suggestion I also want to remove something from `PHP` suggestion and add some for `JavaScript` suggestion.

Any idea how this system works and how to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Changed files will be overwritten whenever a package is updated. While you can exclude third-party packages from being updated, there are many reasons why you shouldn't. In the case of first-party packages, there's no way to prevent this, unless you stop updating Atom itself.

Comment: Okay so is there any way that I can make my own package? I can disable atom `autocomplete-plus` package use my own. Is there any documentation about that? Atom documentation is unfortunately very poor.

Comment: I would probably fork the package that provides these autocompletions and make those changes. There are other ways, of course, but that's a whole new topic that's bigger than your original question.

Comment: Yeah I have that for very long time, it always disturbs me. I will keep trying to find a way thanks for leading.